# How do I access the cppfront executable's help doc?

Tags: cppfront

I tried running `cppfront --help`, and got the following output:

```
--help...
--help: error: source filename must end with .cpp2 or .h2: --help
```

I expected using `--help` to cause the cppfront executable to print its help message / doc string. `--help` is a pretty conventional flag / argument for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct flag to use to get cppfront to print its help doc is `-help` (one leading dash instead of two). You can also use `-?`. And flags can be led with `/` instead of `-` too.

Once you know that and print the help string, you'll see that cppfront doesn't follow the relatively common pattern of using two dashes for long-form commandline arguments / flags, and instead uses a single leading dash for everything. I suppose that's in line with a lot of [GCC's arguments / flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html), but even GCC uses two dashes for `--help` and has no `-help`.

The source code for printing the help message can (at the time of this writing) be found in [source/common.h](https://github.com/hsutter/cppfront/blob/main/source/common.h) (the `print_help` function).

If you run cppfront with no arguments, it'll actually say the following:

```
cppfront: error: no input files (try -help)
```

There's also a line of code in cppfront that will print a message referencing `-help` if you pass an argument that takes a value but don't pass a value:

```cpp
print("Missing argument to option " + arg->text + " (try -help)\n");
```